# Can I increment a variable, initialised as 0 as an argument in recursive function, and at the end simply append this number to an array?

Tags: python, recursion

I am given a `matrix` containing only `1's` and `0's`, where adjacent 1's (horizontal or vertical, NOT diagonal) form `rivers`. I am asked to return an `array` of all river sizes in the matrix.

e.g. [image]

(Note the order of the river sizes don't matter- they can be in any order) i.e. `[2,1,2,2,5]` is also a valid solution!

I am writing the `recursive` part of the code, where as we explore the matrix, if we stumble on a 1, we will run a recursion to explore its adjacent **left, right,up and down** for any 1's.
The code is quite lengthy, and I don't believe it is necessary for my question. My question is, as I call on the `recursive function`, and I update `currentRiverSize +1` (initialised as 0) in the argument of the recursive function as we stumble across more 1's, can I then at the end simply `append` this to the array?

I have a feeling the recursion is not structured correctly!

```
def findAllRiverSizes(matrix): 
    riverSizes = []
    exploreRiver(matrix,row,col,entryExplored,riverSizes,0): 

def exploreRiver(matrix,row,col,entryExplored,riverSizes,currentRiverSize): 
    #look right: 
    if col<len(matrix[0])-1 and not entryExplored[row][col+1] and matrix[row][col+1] == 1: 
        entryExplored[row][col+1] = True
        exploreRiver(matrix,row,col+1,entryExplored,riverSizes,currentRiverSize +1)
    #look left
    if col>0 and not entryExplored[row][col-1] and matrix[row][col-1] == 1: 
        entryExplored[row][col-1] = True
        exploreRiver(matrix,row,col-1,entryExplored,riverSizes,currentRiverSize +1)
    #look up 
    if row >0 and not entryExplored[row-1][col] and matrix[row-1][col]  == 1: 
        entryExplored[row-1][col] = True
        exploreRiver(matrix,row-1,col,entryExplored,riverSizes,currentRiverSize +1)
    #look down
    if row <len(matrix)-1 and not entryExplored[row+1][col] and matrix[row+1][col]  == 1: 
        entryExplored[row+1][col] = True
        exploreRiver(matrix,row+1,col,entryExplored,riverSizes,currentRiverSize +1)
        
    riverSizes.append(currentRiverSize)
    
    return riverSizes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of your code doesn't seem to be doing what you describe you want it to be doing.
Some suggestions -

- Instead of using the 4 different conditions try to use a single condition at the top which checks for the bounds
- Are we allowed to modify the matrix? In that case we can do away without the `entryExplored`
- We don't need to pass the `riverSizes` to the DFS recursion function(since we only need to append the value to `riverSizes` once per DFS run), so we can make the function return that value instead.

Here's a simplified code that does what you want -

```
def findAllRiverSizes(matrix): 
    def exploreRiverDFS(matrix,row,col):
        # go through all neighbors of(row,col) having value 1,
        # set the value to 0(or use entryExplored). In the end after
        # there are no neighbors append the currentRiverSize to riverSizes
        # return the size of this river

        # check if current row, col is valid or there is no river in the current cell
        if (row < 0 or row >= len(matrix) or col < 0 or col >= len(matrix[row])
            or matrix[row][col] == 0):
            return 0

        matrix[row][col] = 0
        return 1 + sum([exploreRiverDFS(matrix, row+1, col),
                        exploreRiverDFS(matrix, row-1, col),
                        exploreRiverDFS(matrix, row, col+1),
                        exploreRiverDFS(matrix, row, col-1)])

    riverSizes = []
    
    # iterate through our matrix here, if we come across a 1, call the DFS function
    # to go through all its neighboring cells and set them to 0 in matrix itself
    # if you are allowed to modify matrix(else you can use entryExplored matrix)
    # the exploreRiverDFS function returns the size of current river it traversed through
    
    for row in range(len(matrix)):
            for col in range(len(matrix[row])):
                if matrix[row][col]:
                    riverSizes.append(exploreRiverDFS(matrix, row, col))
    return riverSizes
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Jay, can I confirm that the time complexity is O(n), where n is the size of the matrix, and the space complexity is O(n) too; due to the recursion stack? Thanks

Comment: Also can I check that I am understand it correctly that when you do "matrix[row][col] = 0" it is to mark the '1' entry as '0' to mark it as done?

Comment: Yes, the time complexity would be O(n) where n is the size of the matrix. And space complexity would be the size of the largest river in the matrix which would be O(n) (in worst case when matrix has all 1's).

By setting matrix[row][col] to 0, we ensure that the particular cell doesn't get counted again(either in the recursion, or when looking for another disconnected river in the lower loop.